# Give radius to bars in bar graph

Tags: reactjs, graph, bar-chart, recharts, react-chartjs-2

Apply border radius to the bars of Bar_Chart using react-chartjs-2 module so please suggest changes in this code only.
i tried radius in data component but it didn't work .

```
import { Bar } from 'react-chartjs-2';

<Bar 
        data={{
          labels :['2020-10-26', '2020-10-27', '2020-10-28', '2020-10-29'],
          
          
          datasets: [
            {
              label: 'r',
              data: [130,220,310,420],
              backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 144, 18)',
             
              
            },
            {
              label: 'm',
              data: [100,200,149,330],
              backgroundColor: '#66CCFF',
              
            },
            {
              label: 'u',
              data: [90,150,30,240],
              backgroundColor: '#00FF99',
              
            },
          ],
        }}
        options={{
          responsive: true,
          cornerRadius:19,
          // plugins: {
          legend: {
            cursor: "pointer",
            display:true,
            position:'bottom',
            labels: {
              usePointStyle: true,
              boxWidth:10,
              }
            },
            
            
          // },
          scales: {
            xAxes: [{
              gridLines: {
                  display:false
              }
          }]}
        }} 
        
        margin={{
          top: 5,
          right: 30,
          left: 20,
          bottom: 5,
        }} 
      />
```

**Want my bars to be round from above like this only visuals are example not code**

*https://codepen.io/jordanwillis/pen/jBoppb*

Answer (score 1):

You have to apply **borderRadius** parameter in datasets as per below code

```
datasets: [
            {
              label: 'r',
              data: [130,220,310,420],
              backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 144, 18)',
              borderRadius : 50  // You can apply any value as per your requirement
              
            },
            {
              label: 'm',
              data: [100,200,149,330],
              backgroundColor: '#66CCFF',
              borderRadius : 50 
            },
            {
              label: 'u',
              data: [90,150,30,240],
              backgroundColor: '#00FF99',
              borderRadius : 50 
            }]
```

Comment: Tried before but not working

Answer (score 1):

Try `borderRadius` in options object instead

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31909486)

Answer (score 1):

check my configs here:

```
const config = {
  type: 'bar',
  data: data,
  maintainAspectRatio: false,
   borderRadius: 7, // radius of the bar
 options: {
   scales: {
     y: {
      beginAtZero: true
    }
  }
},
  plugins: {
  legend: {
  position: 'top' as const,
  align: 'end' as const
  },
  title: {
  display: true,
  text: 'Statistics: Average IQ by age',
  color: '#00121C',
  align: 'start' as const,
  font: {
    size: 24
    }
   }
  }
};
```

For the option object